# How to use RxJs 6 with TypeScript and WebPack

Tags: typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

I followed this tutorial (really straightforward):
https://www.techiediaries.com/rxjs-tutorial/

My index.ts looks like this:

```
import { Observable, Observer } from "rxjs";
import { map } from "rxjs/operators"

console.log(Observable);

var observable = Observable.create((observer:Observer<string>) => {
    observer.next('Hello');
    observer.next('Hello Again');
    observer.complete();
});

observable.map((s:string) => s).subscribe((x:any) => {
    console.log(x);
});
```

webpack-dev-server starts without problem. It seems that "Observable.create" also works.

My problem: not a single operator will work. I get the errror when I open the page:

> Uncaught TypeError: observable.map is not a function

I am searching for 2 hours now - every article explains that this should be the correct way to use RxJs 6 with TypeScript.

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es6",
    "allowJs": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

My webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.ts',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.tsx?$/,
          use: 'ts-loader',
          exclude: /node_modules/
        }
      ]
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ]
    },
    output: {
      filename: 'bundle.js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your're using the old syntax for operators. The current one consists in using [pipeable operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md):

```
import { Observable, Observer } from "rxjs";
import { map } from "rxjs/operators"

console.log(Observable);

var observable = Observable.create((observer:Observer<string>) => {
    observer.next('Hello');
    observer.next('Hello Again');
    observer.complete();
});

observable.pipe(
  map(s => s.toLowercase())
).subscribe(s => console.log(s));
```

Note: your map didn't do anything useful, so I made it do something. Using `any` is really a bad idea, so I removed that too, in addition to using type inference.